# API for capturing sound on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, audio

I need a C++ API to enumerate input devices and capture sound for Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows 8. If there is no common API I can use OS specific API for different versions of Windows.

I found some references on Microsoft site, but I don't know what to chose. What do you recommend?

Comment: Well, it depends on what do you want to use: waveIn API, Core Audio API (not available on XP), DirectShow?

Comment: @user1764961 I don't want to use something specific. Now I'm in the "research" phase and I need to chose one, but I don't know what to chose.

Comment: Is ASIO API by Steinberg beyond or not able to do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For waveIn API use waveInGetNumDevs() and waveInGetDevCaps().
For Core Audio API use IMMDeviceEnumerator.
For DirectShow read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377566(v=vs.85).aspx

It all depends on the rest of the architecture. You have to do something with the captured PCM and you probably know what. That should help you decide what technology to use.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [**BASS library**](http://www.un4seen.com/).

It is:

- cross-platform;
- [**well documented**](http://www.un4seen.com/doc/#bass/RECORDPROC.html);
- has a great support;
- easy to use;
- has lots of plugins;
- **free for non-commercial use**.

Get the total number of recording devices currently present:

```
int a, count=0;
BASS_DEVICEINFO info;
for (a=0; BASS_RecordGetDeviceInfo(a, &info); a++)
    if (info.flags&BASS_DEVICE_ENABLED) // device is enabled
        count++; // count it
```

Start recording at 44100hz 16-bit stereo:

```
FILE *file;
...
// the recording callback
BOOL CALLBACK MyRecordingWriter(HRECORD handle, void *buf, DWORD len, void *user)
{
    fwrite(buf, 1, len, file); // write the buffer to the file
    return TRUE; // continue recording
}
...
HRECORD record=BASS_RecordStart(44100, 2, 0, MyRecordingWriter, 0); // start recording
```

Comment: BASS Library is not free

Answer (score 1):

Below code uses winapi to record sound and save it as .wav file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Mmsystem.h>

#define ALIAS "random_str"

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    printf("|-----------------------|\n" \
           "|Simple Winapi Recorder |\n" \
           "|By @systheron          |\n" \
           "|-----------------------|\n");
    char mci_command[100];
    char ReturnString[300];
    int mci_error;

    sprintf(mci_command, "open new type waveaudio alias %s", ALIAS);
    mci_error = mciSendString(mci_command, ReturnString, sizeof(ReturnString), NULL);

    // set the time format
    sprintf(mci_command,"set %s time format ms", ALIAS);    // just set time format
    mci_error = mciSendString(mci_command, ReturnString, sizeof(ReturnString), NULL);

    // start recording
    sprintf(mci_command, "record %s notify", ALIAS);
    mci_error = mciSendString(mci_command, ReturnString, sizeof(ReturnString), NULL);

    printf("Now recording, get key input to stop...\n");
    char c= getc(stdin);

    //stop recording
    sprintf(mci_command,"stop %s", ALIAS);
    mci_error = mciSendString(mci_command, ReturnString, sizeof(ReturnString), NULL);

    // save the file
    sprintf(mci_command, "save %s %s", ALIAS, "random.wav");
    mci_error = mciSendString(mci_command, ReturnString, sizeof(ReturnString), NULL);

    // close the device
    sprintf(mci_command,"close %s", ALIAS);
    mci_error = mciSendString(mci_command, ReturnString, sizeof(ReturnString), NULL);
    printf("Recording stopped. Congrat, your file is save as: random.wav. \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Using g++ :

```
g++ index.cpp -o index.exe -lWinmm
```

Note: use the -lWinmm to link Mmsystem.h manually